# Combine or join numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, vectorization

How can I join two numpy ndarrays to accomplish the following in a fast way, using optimized numpy, without any looping?

```
>>> a = np.random.rand(2,2)
>>> a
array([[ 0.09028802,  0.2274419 ],
       [ 0.35402772,  0.87834376]])

>>> b = np.random.rand(2,2)
>>> b
array([[ 0.4776325 ,  0.73690098],
       [ 0.69181444,  0.672248  ]])

>>> c = ???
>>> c
array([[ 0.09028802,  0.2274419, 0.4776325 ,  0.73690098],
       [ 0.09028802,  0.2274419, 0.69181444,  0.672248  ],
       [ 0.35402772,  0.87834376, 0.4776325 ,  0.73690098],
       [ 0.35402772,  0.87834376, 0.69181444,  0.672248  ]])
```

Comment: `np.hstack((a[[0, 0, 1, 1]], b[[0, 1, 0, 1]])` will do this. Presumably someone can come up with a more general way of doing it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's walk through a prospective solution to handle generic cases involving different shaped arrays with some inlined comments to explain the method involved.

(1) First off, we store shapes of input arrays.

```
ma,na = a.shape
mb,nb = b.shape
```

(2) Next up, initialize a 3D array with number of columns being the sum of number of columns in input arrays`a` and `b`. Use [`np.empty`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html) for this task.

```
out = np.empty((ma,mb,na+nb),dtype=a.dtype)
```

(3) Then, set the first axis of the 3D array for the first "na" columns with the rows from `a` with `a[:,None,:]`. So, if we assign it to `out[:,:,:na]`, that second colon would indicate to NumPy that we need a broadcasted setting, if possible as always happens with singleton dims in NumPy arrays. In effect, this would be same as tiling/repeating, but possibly in an efficient way.

```
out[:,:,:na] = a[:,None,:]
```

(4) Repeat for setting elements from `b` into output array. This time we would broadcast along the first axis of `out` with `out[:,:,na:]`, with that first colon helping us do that broadcasting.

```
out[:,:,na:] = b
```

(5) Final step is to reshape the output to a 2D shape. This could be done with simply changing the shape with the required 2D shape tuple. Reshaping just changes view and is effectively zero cost.

```
out.shape = (ma*mb,na+nb)
```

---

Condensing everything, the full implementation would look like this -

```
ma,na = a.shape
mb,nb = b.shape
out = np.empty((ma,mb,na+nb),dtype=a.dtype)
out[:,:,:na] = a[:,None,:]
out[:,:,na:] = b
out.shape = (ma*mb,na+nb)
```

Comment: Not a pretty one liner, but faster.

Comment: @hpaulj Sometimes the ugly ones are the fast ones :)

Comment: @Divakar I am kinda surprised that this works. I didn't realize you could just assign a `shape` tuple. Can you explain exactly what's happening?

Comment: @Paul Check out the edits please. Hope those make sense :)

Comment: @Divakar Thank you for the answer and additional color. I selected this as the answer for 3 reasons: 1) handles generic case, 2) numpy only and 3) performance. Paul's answer is also very good IMO.

Comment: @HelloWorld Sounds fair to me! :)

Answer (score 3):

What you want is, apparently, the cartesian product of `a` and `b`, stacked horizontally. You can use the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) module to generate the indices for the numpy arrays, then `numpy.hstack` to stack them:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import product

a = np.array([[ 0.09028802,  0.2274419 ],
              [ 0.35402772,  0.87834376]])

b = np.array([[ 0.4776325 ,  0.73690098],
              [ 0.69181444,  0.672248  ],
              [ 0.79941110,  0.52273   ]])

a_inds, b_inds = map(list, zip(*product(range(len(a)), range(len(b)))))

c = np.hstack((a[a_inds], b[b_inds]))
```

This results in a `c` of:

```
array([[ 0.09028802,  0.2274419 ,  0.4776325 ,  0.73690098],
       [ 0.09028802,  0.2274419 ,  0.69181444,  0.672248  ],
       [ 0.09028802,  0.2274419 ,  0.7994111 ,  0.52273   ],
       [ 0.35402772,  0.87834376,  0.4776325 ,  0.73690098],
       [ 0.35402772,  0.87834376,  0.69181444,  0.672248  ],
       [ 0.35402772,  0.87834376,  0.7994111 ,  0.52273   ]])
```

Breaking down the indices thing:

`product(range(len(a)), range(len(b))` will generate something that looks like this if you convert it to a list:

```
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
```

You want something like this: `[0, 0, 1, 1]`, `[0, 1, 0, 1]`, so you need to transpose the generator. The idiomatic way to do this is with `zip(*zipped_thing)`. However, if you just directly assign these, you'll get `tuples`, like this:

```
[(0, 0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 0, 1)]
```

But numpy arrays interpret tuples as multi-dimensional indexes, so you want to turn them to lists, which is why I mapped the `list` constructor onto the result of the `product` function.

Answer (score 3):

Not the prettiest, but you could combine `hstack`, `repeat`, and `tile`:

```
>>> a = np.arange(4).reshape(2,2)
>>> b = a+10
>>> a
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3]])
>>> b
array([[10, 11],
       [12, 13]])
>>> np.hstack([np.repeat(a,len(a),0),np.tile(b,(len(b),1))])
array([[ 0,  1, 10, 11],
       [ 0,  1, 12, 13],
       [ 2,  3, 10, 11],
       [ 2,  3, 12, 13]])
```

Or for a 3x3 case:

```
>>> a = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
>>> b = a+10
>>> np.hstack([np.repeat(a,len(a),0),np.tile(b,(len(b),1))])
array([[ 0,  1,  2, 10, 11, 12],
       [ 0,  1,  2, 13, 14, 15],
       [ 0,  1,  2, 16, 17, 18],
       [ 3,  4,  5, 10, 11, 12],
       [ 3,  4,  5, 13, 14, 15],
       [ 3,  4,  5, 16, 17, 18],
       [ 6,  7,  8, 10, 11, 12],
       [ 6,  7,  8, 13, 14, 15],
       [ 6,  7,  8, 16, 17, 18]])
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you very much. I know I did not specify in my question, but if a and b are different dimensions, your solution generates an error. The following edit corrects that case:     `np.hstack([np.repeat(a,len(b),0),np.tile(b,(len(a),1))])`

Comment: Actually, my above suggestion does not work. But try with `b = np.random.rand(3,2)` I see `ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly`

Comment: @HelloWorld: the above was done under the assumption that `a` and `b` were both square and the same shape, like in your example. Do you need to handle the general case?

Comment: I do need to handle the general case, but your answer is correct for the question I asked. I did get this far: `np.repeat(a[np.newaxis,:], b.shape[0], axis=1)[0,:]`

Comment: @HelloWorld Not to toot my own horn, but my answer below works just fine for matrices of two different shapes.

Comment: @Paul: True. Both solutions are correct for the question as asked. Your solution also handles this case I mentioned. I am testing it now for performance compared to DSM's numpy only solution.

Comment: @HelloWorld Be sure to check out all the approaches listed :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dstack()` and `broadcast_arrays()`:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randint(0, 10, (3, 2))
b = np.random.randint(10, 20, (4, 2))

np.dstack(np.broadcast_arrays(a[:, None], b)).reshape(-1, a.shape[-1] + b.shape[-1])
```

Comment: This use of `broadcast_arrays` is clever, but slower than the one with `repeat` and `tile`.

Answer (score 0):

Try either np.hstack or np.vstack.  This would work even for arrays that are not the same length.  All you would need to do is this:
np.hstack(appendedarray[:]) or np.vstack(appendedarray[:])

Answer (score -1):

All arrays are indexable, so you can merge the by just calling:

```
a[:2],b[:2]
```

or you can use core numpy stacking functions, should look something like this:

```
c = np.vstack(a,b)
```

Comment: The first thing just creates a 2-ple. The second one doesn't work, but even if it did, it would just append b to a. The OP wants a numpy array that is the cartesian product of the two arrays.